# The process cannot access the file '*.doc' because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I have a number of files that are created, saved, printed and then deleted.  I don't open them. The last file to be deleted is held by another process so it can not be deleted.

This is the error message:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\34_Temp.doc' because it is being used by another process.

This is where I save the file. I use a third party control (Spire .doc for .NET) to create the document. It is also closed after it is saved.

```
 Dim tFname As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & Now.ToString("hhmmss") & g.ToString() & "_Temp.doc"
 OrderDetailsDoc.SaveToFile(tFname, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Doc)
 OrderDetailsDoc.Close()
 SendMetoPrint(tFname)
 OrderDetailsDoc = Nothing
```

This is the Print Procedure:

```
 Public Sub SendMetoPrint(ByVal tmpFilename As String)
    Const csSUBNAME As String = "SendMetoPrint"

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Using dialog As New PrintDialog()
        Dim d As New Spire.Doc.Document(tmpFilename)
        d.PrintDialog = dialog
        dialog.Document = d.PrintDocument

        dialog.AllowCurrentPage = True
        dialog.AllowSomePages = True
        dialog.UseEXDialog = False
        dialog.PrintToFile = False

        dialog.Document.Print()
        d.Close()
        d.PrintDocument.Dispose()
        d = Nothing

    End Using

    End Sub
```

This is what I use to delete the files. The thread sleep doesn't help. I was hoping this would give the process time to release the file, but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub ClearFolder(ByVal dirString As String)

    Dim foundFile As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each foundFile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(dirString, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*Temp.doc")
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(foundFile) Then
            For i = 1 To 10
                Try
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(foundFile)
                    Exit For
                Catch ex As Exception
                    If i = 10 Then
                        Logit(Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") & "  " & csSUBNAME)
                        Logit(Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") & "  Unable to delete file " & foundFile & " after 10 tries over 10 seconds.")
                        Logit(Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") & "  Exception says: " & ex.Message)
                    Else
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    End If
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

This is the sub that is called to print multiple orders. The screen contains a listing of orders to be printed.

A loop through each order to get order detail is necessary:

```
Public Sub PrintAllOrders(Optional ByVal printbatchnum As Integer = 0)

    Const csSUBNAME As String = "PrintAllOrders"
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim objPrintPick As clsPickScreen
    Dim argWorkObject As clsWorkOrder
    Dim strErrorLocation As String = ""
    Dim pbn As Integer
    Dim g As Integer = 0
    Dim rsBatchReprint As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim OrderDetailsDoc As New Spire.Doc.Document

    frmPickScreen.PickPrint = True

        pbn = GeneratePrtBatchNum()
        strErrorLocation = "Just generated Print Batch Number"

        For Each objPrintPick In objTotalPickScreen

            blnRedPrint = objPrintPick.AlreadyPrinted

            If objPrintPick.printed = False Then

                objPrintPick.printed = True
                g = g + 1

                argWorkObject = New clsWorkOrder
                argWorkObject.Connection = conSQLDatabase

                argWorkObject.UserID = gstrUserID
                argWorkObject.Role = gconPICKING_ROLE
                argWorkObject.OrderID = objPrintPick.OrderID
                argWorkObject.SubOrderID = objPrintPick.SubOrderID
                argWorkObject.SubOrderPickScrnStatus = CShort(objPrintPick.Status)
                argWorkObject.StoreNumber = objPrintPick.FulfillStore
                argWorkObject.LoadWorkOrder()
                argWorkObject.PrintBatchNumber = pbn


                Call SpirePrintOrder(argWorkObject, (gobjOptions.PrintMultiCopies), OrderDetailsDoc)
                InsertNewPage(OrderDetailsDoc)


            End If


            If g Mod 10 = 0 And g > 0 Then

                Dim tFname As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & Now.ToString("hhmmss") & g.ToString() & "_Temp.doc"
                OrderDetailsDoc.SaveToFile(tFname, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Doc)
                OrderDetailsDoc.Close()
                SendMetoPrint(tFname)
                'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tFname)

                OrderDetailsDoc = Nothing
                OrderDetailsDoc = New Spire.Doc.Document
            End If

        Next objPrintPick


        If g = 0 Then
            MsgBox("There are no unprinted orders.")
            frmPickScreen.cmdPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
            frmPickScreen.cmdPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        Else

            strErrorLocation = "About to Send Order to Printer - Outside Loop"
            Dim tFname As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & Now.ToString("hhmmss") & g.ToString() & "_Temp.doc"
            OrderDetailsDoc.SaveToFile(tFname, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Doc)
            OrderDetailsDoc.Close()
            SendMetoPrint(tFname)
            OrderDetailsDoc = Nothing
            'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tFname)
        End If

End Sub


Public Sub SpirePrintOrder(ByRef argWorkObject As clsWorkOrder, ByRef argblnPrintMultiple As Boolean, ByRef OrderDetailsDoc As Document)

    Dim intPageNum As Integer
    Dim intLinesPrinted As Integer
    Dim strErrorLocation As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim blnSpecItem As Boolean
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim lngCountofDepts As Integer
    Dim strPrintDate As String
    Dim strDescPrint As String = ""
    Dim boolPickPrint As Boolean = frmPickScreen.PickPrint
    Dim prodPara As Paragraph
    Dim tmpSec As Section

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim dialog As New PrintDialog()
    dialog.AllowCurrentPage = True
    dialog.AllowSomePages = True
    dialog.UseEXDialog = True

    strErrorLocation = "preparing to print PrintOrder"
    lngCountofDepts = 0
    strPrintDate = CStr(Now)

    dialog = frmPickScreen.cmdPrintDialog
    intNumCopies = dialog.PrinterSettings.Copies
    lngCountofDepts = GetNumberOfDepts((argWorkObject.SubOrderID), (argWorkObject.StoreNumber))


        For g = 1 To lngCountofDepts

            If g > 1 Then
                InsertNewPage(OrderDetailsDoc)
            End If

            For a = 1 To intNumCopies

                Logit(Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss") & "  Number of copies is " & intNumCopies.ToString())
                intPageNum = 1
                iPageLineCounter = 0


                SpirePageHeader(OrderDetailsDoc, argWorkObject, intPageNum, True, False, argblnPrintMultiple, g, lngCountofDepts, strPrintDate)
                SpireStaticHeader(OrderDetailsDoc)



                For x = 1 To argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Count
                    If iPageLineCounter > 35 Then
                        intPageNum += 1

                        InsertNewPage(OrderDetailsDoc)
                        iPageLineCounter = 0

                        SpirePageHeader(OrderDetailsDoc, argWorkObject, intPageNum, True, False, argblnPrintMultiple, g, lngCountofDepts, strPrintDate)
                        SpireStaticHeader(OrderDetailsDoc)

                    End If

                    blnSpecItem = False

                    If argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).IsGiftWrap = True Or argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).MfgRebate = True Then
                        blnSpecItem = True
                    End If

                    strDescPrint = Trim(Left(argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).ItemDescription, 65))
                    If blnSpecItem = True Then
                        strDescPrint = "(SPC ITEM) " & Left(strDescPrint, 54)
                    End If

                    If blnRedPrint = True Then
                        If argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).printed = False Then
                            strDescPrint = "(NEW ITEM) " & Trim(Left(strDescPrint, 54))
                        End If
                    End If

        'Pad all fields displayed on the page for astetic appearance
                    padProduct(argWorkObject, x)
                    addOrderData(argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).ImagePathName, OrderDetailsDoc, strDescPrint)
                    If argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).MfgRebate = True Then

                        tmpSec = OrderDetailsDoc.Sections.LastItem
                        prodPara = tmpSec.Paragraphs(0)
                        prodPara.AppendText(Space(5) & argWorkObject.AllOrderItems.Item(x).MfgRebateMsg & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNReg12Font
                        prodPara.AppendText("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNReg12Font
                        iPageLineCounter += 2
                    End If

                Next


                If UCase(Trim(argWorkObject.ShippingMethod)) = "UPS EXPEDITED" Then

                    If iPageLineCounter > 35 Then

                        SpirePageHeader(OrderDetailsDoc, argWorkObject, intPageNum, True, False, argblnPrintMultiple, g, lngCountofDepts, strPrintDate)

                    End If

                    tmpSec = OrderDetailsDoc.Sections.LastItem
                    prodPara = tmpSec.Paragraphs(0)
                    prodPara.AppendText("  " & vbCrLf)
                    prodPara.AppendText("  " & vbCrLf)
                    prodPara.AppendText(Space(31) & "***************************************************" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNBold12Font
                    prodPara.AppendText(Space(31) & "*  Customer is paying a premium for RUSH service  *" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNBold12Font
                    prodPara.AppendText(Space(31) & "*       Please prioritize Picking & Packing       *" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNBold12Font
                    prodPara.AppendText(Space(31) & "*             Ship UPS Second Day Air             *" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNBold12Font
                    prodPara.AppendText(Space(31) & "***************************************************" & vbCrLf).CharacterFormat.Font = myCNBold12Font

                End If

                If argWorkObject.Comments.CommentsExist = True Then

                    Call SprireComments(OrderDetailsDoc, argWorkObject, intPageNum, iPageLineCounter, argblnPrintMultiple, g, lngCountofDepts, strPrintDate)

                End If

            Next

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You might not open the file, but your printing process certainly does. In your test loop you're only allowing 10 seconds for the print process to complete. I'd guess you're not waiting long enough.

Comment: Can you show the code which calls these Subs? You're not providing the full picture.